# DataExplorer Cannot Create PDF Report

Tags: r, pdf, pandoc

I am trying to generate some reports with the R DataExplorer package, but for some reason, while the html report works like a charm, the creation of a pdf report fails miserably.
It is possible it is a pandoc issue, but please have a look at the reprex at the end of the post.

Any suggestion is welcome!

```r
library(DataExplorer)

create_report(iris
             ,
              output_file = "report.html") ### this works
#> processing file: report.rmd
#> output file: /tmp/RtmpnWllz3/reprex347124a8c7df/report.knit.md
#> /usr/bin/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS /tmp/RtmpnWllz3/reprex347124a8c7df/report.utf8.md --to html4 --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output /tmp/RtmpnWllz3/reprex347124a8c7df/report.html --lua-filter /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/pagebreak.lua --lua-filter /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/latex-div.lua --self-contained --standalone --section-divs --table-of-contents --toc-depth 6 --template /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rmarkdown/rmd/h/default.html --no-highlight --variable highlightjs=1 --variable 'theme:yeti' --include-in-header /tmp/RtmpDWU78N/rmarkdown-str348854cbcbb6.html --mathjax --variable 'mathjax-url:https://mathjax.rstudio.com/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML'
#> 
#> Output created: report.html


## but this does not!


create_report(iris
             ,
              output_file = "report.pdf") 
#> processing file: report.rmd
#> output file: /tmp/RtmpnWllz3/reprex347124a8c7df/report.knit.md
#> /usr/bin/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS /tmp/RtmpnWllz3/reprex347124a8c7df/report.utf8.md --to html4 --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output /tmp/RtmpnWllz3/reprex347124a8c7df/report.pdf --lua-filter /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/pagebreak.lua --lua-filter /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/latex-div.lua --self-contained --standalone --section-divs --table-of-contents --toc-depth 6 --template /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rmarkdown/rmd/h/default.html --no-highlight --variable highlightjs=1 --variable 'theme:yeti' --include-in-header /tmp/RtmpDWU78N/rmarkdown-str348863c0475e.html --mathjax --variable 'mathjax-url:https://mathjax.rstudio.com/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML'
#> Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 1

## how to fix it....


print(sessionInfo())
#> R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15)
#> Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
#> Running under: Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
#> 
#> Matrix products: default
#> BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas/libblas.so.3
#> LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenblasp-r0.3.5.so
#> 
#> locale:
#>  [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
#>  [3] LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8    
#>  [5] LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8   
#>  [7] LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
#>  [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
#> [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       
#> 
#> attached base packages:
#> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
#> 
#> other attached packages:
#> [1] knitr_1.31         rmarkdown_2.6      data.table_1.13.6  DataExplorer_0.8.2
#> 
#> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#>  [1] Rcpp_1.0.6        plyr_1.8.6        pillar_1.4.7      compiler_4.0.4   
#>  [5] highr_0.8         tools_4.0.4       digest_0.6.27     jsonlite_1.7.2   
#>  [9] evaluate_0.14     lifecycle_1.0.0   tibble_3.0.6      gtable_0.3.0     
#> [13] pkgconfig_2.0.3   rlang_0.4.10      reprex_1.0.0      igraph_1.2.6     
#> [17] DBI_1.1.1         curl_4.3          parallel_4.0.4    yaml_2.2.1       
#> [21] xfun_0.21         gridExtra_2.3     xml2_1.3.2        httr_1.4.2       
#> [25] styler_1.3.2      stringr_1.4.0     dplyr_1.0.4       generics_0.1.0   
#> [29] fs_1.5.0          vctrs_0.3.6       htmlwidgets_1.5.3 grid_4.0.4       
#> [33] tidyselect_1.1.0  glue_1.4.2        R6_2.5.0          reshape2_1.4.4   
#> [37] farver_2.0.3      ggplot2_3.3.3     purrr_0.3.4       magrittr_2.0.1   
#> [41] backports_1.2.1   scales_1.1.1      ellipsis_0.3.1    htmltools_0.5.1.1
#> [45] networkD3_0.4     assertthat_0.2.1  mime_0.10         colorspace_2.0-0 
#> [49] labeling_0.4.2    stringi_1.5.3     munsell_0.5.0     crayon_1.4.1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug in `DataExplorer::create_report()` because it uses a custom R Markdown template where there are functions that produce an output in HTML format. This causes an error when producing an output in PDF. I proposed a correction on the author's GitHub, and I will update this answer if the correction is accepted.

However, there is also something to change in your code. You need to call:

```
create_report(iris, output_file = "report.pdf", output_format = "pdf_document")
```

and not:

```
create_report(iris, output_file = "report.pdf")
```

---

In the meantime, you can edit the Rmd template provided by `DataExplorer`:

- locate the file with: `system.file("rmd_template/report.Rmd", package = "DataExplorer")`
- open it, and add `always_allow_html: true` in the YAML (just after the `title:` part)

Running `create_report(iris, output_file = "report.pdf", output_format = "pdf_document")` should now work. Note however that this correction will disappear if you update the package.

Comment: Thanks. Good to know at least that there is a potential fix for this in the pipeline.

Comment: @larry77 You can already correct the package locally, I added a brief explanation on how to do it.